# Angular, How to filter through json using Angular?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple Json and I need to filter the objects based on a name, In this example I have two movie titles "Paddington" and "Interstaller" and lets say I only want to filter out by name "Paddington" and set the $scope only to the first item "Paddington" item

```
{
"feed": {
    "author": {
        "name": {
            "label": "iTunes Store"
        },
        "uri": {
            "label": "http://www.apple.com/itunes/"
        }
    },
    "entry": [
        {
            "im:name": {
                "label": "Paddington"
            }, 
            "im:image": [
                {
                    "label": "url1",
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "label": "url2",
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "label": "url3",
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "170"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "im:name": {
                "label": "Interstellar"
            },"im:image": [
                {
                    "label": "url4",
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "label": "url5",
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "label": "url6",
                    "attributes": {
                        "height": "170"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updated": {
        "label": "2015-04-18T11:29:36-07:00"
    },
    "rights": {
        "label": "Copyright 2008 Apple Inc."
    },
    "title": {
        "label": "iTunes Store: Top Movies"
    }
}
```

My code

```
    app.controller('movieController', function ($scope, $routeParams, movieService) {

  $scope.filterData = function init(){
    $scope.movies =  movieService.get({id: 4403});// returns the json
    var filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.movies.entry, function(value,index){
      return value["im:name"].label.indexOf("The Sound")!=-1;
    });
    $scope.firstItem = filtered[0];
  };


  alert($scope.firstItem);

});


app.factory('movieService',function ($resource) {
  return $resource('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=50/genre=:id/json', {id: '@id'});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $filter service will let you fetch a filter function, there is a filter function called 'filter' that is built in.  Documentation here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

```
app.controller('movieController', function ($scope, $filter, $routeParams, movieService) {

  alert($routeParams.movieID);
  $scope.movies = movieService.get({id: 4403});// returns the json
  $scope.movies.$promise.then(function(resp){
    var filterFunc = $filter('filter');
    var filtered = filterFunc($scope.movies.feed.entry, function(value,index){
      return value["im:name"].label.indexOf($routeParams.movieID)!=-1;
    });
    $scope.firstItem = filtered[0]; // could put this in place of movies but it's confusing since you're re-using that name for the initial resource and this filtered item
  });


  function test() {

    alert(movieService.get({id: 4403}).entry.summary.label);
  };
  $scope.movies.name = {}; // need to return Paddington
  $scope.movies.url = {}; // need to return url3


});

app.factory('movieService',function ($resource) {
  return $resource('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=50/genre=:id/json', {id: '@id'});
});
```

Comment: where did you pass the "Paddington"?

Comment: @user1429595 "Paddington" would just be passed as the argument to the filterData function it's generic as is, if you want you can get rid of searchText and replace it with "Paddington" if you'll only ever use the function for searching for that string.  Just noticed I had accidentally used value as the param where I wanted searchText so I fixed that above, this is looking for a partial string match so if it finds the searchText as part of the property of the object in the array it will be considered a match, can replace the indexOf line to use == if you want strict equality.

Comment: it didnt do it, I need to pass $routeParams.movieID, would you also add some alerts to the code, I really appreciate it

Comment: Im getting alerted item "undefied", please the latest updates code

Comment: if you would, I'd appreciate it

Comment: @user1429595 Think it should be good now give it another go, the $promise will callback to the function I pass to it there once the data is available then we can filter it.

Comment: still didnt do it and I get undefined

Comment: out of all those list I want to get only of them

Comment: @user1429595 no problem going to take out some of my comments here that aren't relevant

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an AngularJS-specific solution to this problem, it's a generic JavaScript issue. You want to loop through each object in the JSON dictionary and then check the title.

Something like this:

```
data = {
  'feed': {
    'entry': [
      {'im:name': 'Paddington'},
      {'im:name': 'Interstellar'},
    ]
  }
}

$scope.movies.name = null;
for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i += 1) {
  var movie = data.feed.entry.entry[i];
  if (movie['im:name'].indexOf('Paddington') !== -1) {
    $scope.movies.name = movie.title;
    break;
  }
}
```

You can also use the [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) function.

Comment: how do I convert the $scope.movies to data?